# inserting image in database from web

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller

I am trying to get store image in database from web but in this code
Visual Studio is saying "BinaryReader" was not found.

[image: it is the problem]

```
private readonly DBContext db = new DBContext();  

public int UploadImageInDataBase(HttpPostedFileBase file, ContentViewModel contentViewModel)  
{  
    contentViewModel.Image = ConvertToBytes(file);  

    var Content = new Content  
    {  
       Title = contentViewModel.Title,  
       Description = contentViewModel.Description,  
       Contents = contentViewModel.Contents,  
       Image = contentViewModel.Image  
    };  

    db.Contents.Add(Content);  
    int i = db.SaveChanges();  

    if (i == 1)  
    {  
        return 1;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return 0;  
    }  
} 

public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase image)  
{  
     byte[] imageBytes = null;  
     BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);  
     imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.ContentLength);  
     return imageBytes;  
}
```

Comment: What version of the framework are you using ?

Comment: Do you have `using System.IO;` at the top of the file?